# Using Paho to connect to Mosquito MQTT server

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I am trying to use Paho's JavaScript library to connect to a Mosquito MQTT server. I have just used the example on the Paho website. Which is:

```
function onConnect() {
  console.log("onConnect");
  client.subscribe("harleyRowland/myTopic");
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "harleyRowland/myTopic";
  client.send(message); 
}
onConnect();
```

On Safari, I get the following error:

> Error: AMQJS0011E Invalid state not connected.

and on Chrome, I get the following error as well as the one above:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://mosquitoServer.co.uk:1883/mqtt' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I need to use the Mosquito server for this work. Is it possible using JavaScript? If it isn't possible, is there another web technology I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a websockets listener to your mosquitto setup. you do this by adding something like the following to your mosquitto.conf

```
listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

This will listen for MQTT over websockets on port 1884 (not 1883 as you can not run both on the same socket with mosquitto).

You will also need to be running mosquitto newer than 1.4 and not on Windows unless you compile it yourself

Comment: You can use websockets on Windows, you'll just have to compile it yourself.

Comment: I cannot add functionality to the Mosquito server (it doesn't belong to me). Does this make it impossible to interact with MQTT via web?

Comment: If the broker is not configured for websockets then the paho code will not be able to talk to it. It is possible to run raw MQTT to MQTT over Websocket bridges, but you would have to host this somewhere